# Arrows on Circle

Tags: arrows, circles, pspicture

Hello i'm trying to get the arrows on the circles

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)\grilla
\psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt,labels=none,
ticks=none]{-}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\pscircle[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){1}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){2}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){3}
\rput[c](4,0.2){$x$}
\rput[c](0.2,3.8){$y$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is `\grilla`?

Comment: \grilla is grid... \newpsobject{grilla}{psgrid}{subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=6pt}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4.5)(4,4.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psset{arrowscale=1.5}
\multido{\n=1+1}{3}{%
  \psarcn[linewidth=1.1pt]{>->}(0,0){\n}{45}{225}
  \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){\n}{30}{230}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why the radii of arcs and circles get treated differently?

Comment: I cannot see that behaviour

Comment: Please have a look at my [example below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409899/121799) and compile it with ` \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt]{<-}(0,0){\n}{45}{90}` instead of ` \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt]{<-}(0,0){\rad}{45}{90}`. (I had to reduce the radii of the arcs by `1.1pt` in order to have them sit on the circles.)

Comment: @marmot: What do you mean "the radii of arcs and circles get treated differently"? They are different in what? You can play with `dimen`  to avoid such a difference.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Please have a look at my [example below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409899/121799) and compile it with ` \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt]{<-}(0,0){\n}{45}{90}` instead of ` \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt]{<-}(0,0){\rad}{45}{90}. (I had to reduce the radii of the arcs by 1.1pt` in order to have them sit on the circles. Naively, I'd have expected that the same radii should work. Herbert circumvents this issue nicely by also drawing the circles as arcs. BTW, I compile with xelatex.)

Comment: @marmot: use `dimen=middle` for the circle

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Herbert, there is a very simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)%\grilla
\psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt,labels=none,
ticks=none]{-}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\multido{\n=1+1}{3}{
    \pscircle[dimen=middle,linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){\n}
    \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt]{<-}(0,0){\n}{45}{90}
    \psarc[linewidth=1.1pt]{<-}(0,0){\n}{225}{270}}

\rput[c](4,0.2){$x$}
\rput[c](0.2,3.8){$y$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The `dimen=middle` is required since otherwise the radii of the arcs and circles disagree.

[image]

If the aim is to really reproduce the arrows from your picture, you may also use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)%\grilla
\psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt,labels=none,
ticks=none]{-}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\def\mytriangle{\begin{pspicture}(-0.2,-0.2)(0.2,0.2)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](-0.2,0.2)(0.2,0.2)(0,-0.2)
\end{pspicture}
}

\multido{\n=1+1}{3}{
    \pscircle[linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){\n}
    \pstFPmul\rad{\n}{0.707107} % 0.707107 = 1/sqrt(2)
    \rput[c]{45}(\rad,\rad){\mytriangle}
    \rput[c]{225}(-\rad,-\rad){\mytriangle}
    }

\rput[c](4,0.2){$x$}
\rput[c](0.2,3.8){$y$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd be very interested to learn to reproduce the nice curved arrows that come with the `feynmp` package (curved fermion lines) with either pstricks or ti*k*Z.

**UPDATE** Using [AboAmmar's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409905/121799) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409925/121799), one can may bend the arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,bending,arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line width=.7pt]
    \draw (-3.2,0)--(3.2,0)node[right]{$x$} (0,-3.2)--(0,3.2)node[above]{$y$};
    \foreach \r in {1,2,3} 
      {\draw      (0,0) circle (\r);
    \draw[-{Stealth[length=0.3cm,bend]}]  (90:\r) arc (90:45:\r);
    \draw[-{Stealth[length=0.3cm,bend]}]  (270:\r) arc (270:225:\r);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I know and it produced a weird output, please try yourself. (It skipped one circle.)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity That's a matter of taste. Unlike Ti*k*Z, pstricks is perfectly fine with nested picture environments, and my command can also be called outside the picture,

Comment: As I said in my comment to Herbert's answer, play with `dimen`. Anyway, `dimen=m` is enough. Thanks to me. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Also with tikz:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,bending}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line width=.7pt]
    \draw (-3.2,0)--(3.2,0)node[right]{$x$} (0,-3.2)--(0,3.2)node[above]{$y$};
    \foreach \r in {1,2,3} 
      \draw[
      decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow{<}}},
      decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.625 with {\arrow{<}}},
      postaction={decorate}
      ]
      (0,0) circle (\r);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]