# Curved arrow heads with pstricks and/or tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, arrows

Motivated by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409894/arrows-on-circle), I was wondering if there is a way to produce curved arrow heads with either pstricks and/or ti*k*Z (alphabetic ordering;-). To be more specific, I'm interested in something like the top arrow in

[image]

which I produced with the feynmf code

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,22)
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmf{fermion,label={}}{i,v,v,o}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

(I only include the diagram code here because there are different ways of embedding these diagrams in LaTeX documents and please don't worry about the `label={}`. The way this curved arrow is produced is not relevant to the question, anyway.)

Comment: I'm trying to compile the code you provided, but I get a `I detected a fmfgraph environment outside of fmffile`. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: look at nonlinear transforms there is an example in the manual

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The code for the fmfgraph should not be relevant, but I am wrapping the code between `\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{Test}` and `\end{fmffile}  
\end{document}` in a document that loads `\usepackage{feynmp}`. And of course I run mpost.

Comment: @percusse Do you mean the tikz-pgf manual?

Comment: @marmot Ah, sorry. I misunderstood your question `:)`. In this case, I suggest you take a look at page 33 of the [VisualTikZ](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf). Also, try this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[-{Stealth[length=1cm,open,bend]}] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);
\end{document}`. If you like, I make it an answer.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Amazing! Thanks a lot! Want to turn this into an answer? (I'll wait a bit before I accept it in order to see whether there is also a pstricks solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes then `:)`

From page 33 of the [VisualTikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualtikz?lang=en):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% Arrows library for...
\usetikzlibrary{bending}% The bending library is the one that allows the bending of the arrows
\begin{document}
% And a few examples:
\tikz{\draw[-{Latex[length=1cm,open,bend]},thick] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);}
\tikz{\draw[-{Stealth[length=1cm,open,bend]},thick] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);}
\tikz{\draw[-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[length=1cm,open,bend]},thick] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);}
\tikz{\draw[-{Bar[length=1cm,open,bend]},thick] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);}

Something went rwong with this one :P

\tikz{\draw[-{Hooks[length=1cm,open,bend]},thick] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[VisualTikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualtikz?lang=en) and [VisualPSTricks](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualpstricks?lang=en) are excellent for quick reference and for those too lazy to read, like me.

I looked a little but didn't find the corresponding Trick in [VisualPSTricks](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualpstricks?lang=en) (hehe...).